# Scilab Xcos Block Parameters not showing

Tags: scilab, xcos

i tried to change the List of Signs (amount of inputs) in the "SUM_f" Block used from the Palette Browser in Xcos.
Right Click -> Choosing "Block Parameters" from the context menue is not showing any Window.

"6.1.1.1626343451"
"Windows 10 10.0"
"1.8.0_292"
"OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10)"
"OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)"
"Oracle Corporation"